# How do I tail a log file that's being written because of an earlier command in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I'm scripting the installation and configuration procedure for my company's desktop application. We send out a [kiosk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software) and can't put everything in the installer... moving right along! I'm using [`Start-Process`](http://www.i-think22.net/archives/2011/02/06/installing-multiple-msi-files-using-msiexec-exe-and-powershell/) to wait for [`msiexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490936.aspx) to [complete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/11/15/493236.aspx).

```
function Run-Installer
{
    param
    (
        [string] $msi = $(throw "Required parameter: 'msi'"),
    )

    if(-not(Test-Path $msi -Type Leaf))
    {
        throw "The installer could not be found: '$msi'"
    }

    $name = (Get-Item $msi).BaseName

    Write-Host "Installing $name"

    $p = 
    @(
        "/I `"$msi`"",                    # Install this MSI
        "/QN",                            # Quietly, without a UI
        "/L*V `"$ENV:TEMP\$name.log`""    # Verbose output to this log
    )

    Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec" -ArgumentList $p -Wait
}
```

Where I want to get fancy is with the log output from `msiexec`. I want to stream the contents of the log to the console while the installer is running. I'm guessing there are multiple parts to the solution

1. Running the installer in a background, waitable manner
2. Tailing the log file until some condition is met (installer job completes)
3. Optional: Filtering the output or writing to debug/verbose for fun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Start-FileTail {
    param($path)
    # Get unique source ID
    $sourceID = "FileTailLine-" + [guid]::NewGuid()

    $job = Start-Job -ArgumentList $path, $sourceID {
        param($path,$sid)

        Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier $sid -Forward

        do{}until(Test-Path $path)

        $fs = New-Object IO.FileStream ($path, [IO.FileMode]::Open, 
                [IO.FileAccess]::Read, [IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite)
        $sr = New-Object IO.StreamReader ($fs)
        $lines = @()

        while(1) {
            $line = $sr.ReadLine()
            $lines += $line
            # Send after every 100 reads
            if($lines.Count -gt 100) {
                # Join lines into 1 string
                $text = @($lines| where {$_} ) -join "`n"
                # Only send if text was found
                if($text){New-Event -SourceIdentifier $sid -MessageData $text}
                $lines = @()
            }
        }
    }

    $event = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier $sourceID -Action {
        Write-Host $event.MessageData
    }
    New-Object Object|
        Add-Member -Name Job -Type NoteProperty -Value $job -PassThru|
        Add-Member -Name SourceIdentifier -Type NoteProperty -Value $sourceID -PassThru
}

function Stop-FileTail {
    param($TailInfo)
    Remove-Job $TailInfo.Job -Force
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier $tail.SourceIdentifier
}
```

You can remove the job, and unregister the event once the install is done.

Change `Write-Host` to `Write-Verbose` for `-Verbose` support

**EDIT:** I tested my answer while installing an application, and found that it was pretty slow when reading the log file. I updated the `Get-Content` call to use `-ReadCount 100` to send the data as arrays of lines. The `Write-Host` line was updated to handle the arrays.

I also found that using the `-Wait` switch on `Start-Process` caused all of the log output to be written after the install was finished. This can be fixed by using:

```
$msi = Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec" -ArgumentList $p -PassThru
do{}until($msi.HasExited)
```

**EDIT 2:** Hmm, I don't get all of the log file when I use `-Wait` and `-ReadCount` together. I put the reading of the log file back to how I originally had it. I'm not sure what to do about the speed yet.

**EDIT 3:** I've updated the code to use a StreamReader instead of `Get-Content`, and put the code into functions. You would then call it like:

```
$path = "$ENV:TEMP\$name.log"
if(Test-Path $path){Remove-Item $path}

$msi = Start-Process -FilePath "msiexec" -ArgumentList $p -PassThru
$tail = Start-FileTail $p
do{}until($msi.HasExited)
sleep 1 # Allow time to finish reading log.
Stop-FileTail $tail
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the work! I might have time to implement this tonight. I'll be checking back regularly :)

Comment: Still haven't tried the solution, it's for a side project at work and, wouldn't you know it, my main responsibilities keep getting in the way :) However, you've waited long enough for the rep!